# Loading 3rd party script overrides the styles of my site completely

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

When I load my page to check the remainder of gift card balance (from a 3rd party script) it overrides the styles that I have on my site. Below is an example of my code:

```
<div id="main" class="main">
    <div id="giftcard-balance-container" class="giftcard-balance-container">
        <div id="chockstone-loading" class="chockstone-loading">
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
        <script>
            var container = document.getElementById('giftcard-balance-container');
            while (container == null) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    container = document.getElementById('giftcard-balance-container');
                }, 100);
            }

            var addListener = function (script, callback) {
                if (callback !== null) {
                    if (script.readyState) { // IE, in¡cl. IE9
                        script.onreadystatechange = function onReadyStateChange() {
                            if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
                                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                                callback();
                            }
                        };
                    } else {
                        script.onload = function onLoad() { // Other browsers
                            callback();
                        };
                    }
                }
            };

            var scriptLoaded = function () {
                var loading = document.getElementById('chockstone-loading');
                loading.parentNode.removeChild(loading);
            };

            try {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = 'SCRIPT_URL_REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY_REASONS';
                container.appendChild(script);
                addListener(script, scriptLoaded);
            } catch (e) {

            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it so the script doesn't override my styles that I currently have?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by overrides your styles. Are you saying that the script you are bringing in actually sets new CSS for your elements. Are they using the same ids etc? It seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` in your style

Example

```
.your-class{
   color:#ffffff !important;
}
```